# BaseExpandableListAdapter's strange behavior

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView and I'm using an adapter to inflate groups and children rows from layout XMLs. In my child XML I have 3 text views: name, notes and amount. What I want is:
if child's object amount > 1 display it in the appropriate text view; set notes text view's text to child's details field, but if the details string is empty - make the view disappeared.

So I had this code in my adapter:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ChildHolder child_holder;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_selected_item_packed, null);
        child_holder = new ChildHolder();
        child_holder.tv_si_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_packed_item_name);
        child_holder.tv_si_notes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_packed_item_notes);
        child_holder.tv_si_amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_packed_item_amount);
        child_holder.img_packed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_packed);
        convertView.setTag(child_holder);
    } else {
        child_holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Selected_Group selected_group = arr_selected_groups.get(groupPosition);
    final Selected_Item selected_item = selected_group.getArr_selected_items().get(childPosition);

    if(selected_item!=null)
    {
        child_holder.tv_si_name.setText(selected_item.getItem_name());

        //Here starts the problem
        child_holder.tv_si_notes.setText(selected_item.getSelected_item_details());
        if(selected_item.getSelected_item_details().equals(""))
        {
            child_holder.tv_si_notes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(selected_item.getSelected_item_amount()>1)
        {
            child_holder.tv_si_amount.setText(String.valueOf(selected_item.getSelected_item_amount()));
        }

        if(selected_item.isSelected_item_packed())
        {
            child_holder.img_packed.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_packed));
        } else {
            child_holder.img_packed.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_unchecked));
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

class ChildHolder{
    TextView tv_si_name;
    TextView tv_si_notes;
    TextView tv_si_amount;
    ImageView img_packed;
}
```

Currently I only have 1 child that has both amount>1 (all the rest have 1) and details. But here's what happens:

1. All the notes text views are gone. If I remove the if statement - they appear and the text is set in the appropriate child.
2. First I have the amount text exactly in the right child. However if I close the group and reopen it - suddenly another child has that same amount (and if the `if` statement from #1 is gone - then the details are also being duplicated to that child. If I open another group - I'll see the amount on one of its children too. So eventually if I keep opening and closing groups I'll have amount in every child's amount text view.

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this way..

```
child_holder.tv_si_notes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if(selected_item.getSelected_item_details().equals(""))
{
   child_holder.tv_si_notes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
   child_holder.tv_si_notes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Well, looks like it solved the Notes text view issue, but the amount still duplicates itself to other children when I open/close the groups...

Comment: what you need if amount<=0?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you meant... The amount value is never 0, it'll always by 1 or higher.

Comment: Looks like a simple `else` statement solved that problem: `else { child_holder.tv_si_amount.setText(""); }`. But I still wonder why did it happen. Very weird problem. Still, thanks for the help! Appreciate it!